# Heroku rake jobs:work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

I'm running delayed jobs on my heroku-hosted application and, naturally enough, the jobs only run when I have ran 'heroku rake jobs:work' in a terminal window. However, when I close the terminal window, the job seems to stop processing.

Is there a way to run this job independently of my terminal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need workers for delayed job to work. You can add them in your console:

```
heroku workers 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, just add a worker at Heroku in the resource panel of your app. It should work automatically on Aspen and Bamboo stacks, and for Cedar stacks and more information about Heroku and DJ be sure to checkout the [article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job) at Heroku's devcenter:

[image]